# Persist Django user in session

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-authentication

I am using [RemoteUserMiddleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/auth-remote-user/) to authenticate with [VAS](https://www.symantec.com/security_response/glossary/define.jsp?letter=v&word=vas-veritas-authentication-service).

Right now I set it up so the `REMOTE_USER` variable gets set only for my SSO login URL (`/accounts/login/sso/`), because I must allow my users to login via forms (for users not present in our SSO system). According to my debugging, the user gets authenticated correctly in `VasMiddleware` (which extends `RemoteUserMiddleware` to pre-process `REMOTE_USER`), but after the user gets redirected to the home page (`/`), authentication is lost.

How can I persist the information that user has been logged in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Django 1.9](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.9/#django-contrib-auth) will have a [`PersistentRemoteUserMiddleware`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/middleware/#django.contrib.auth.middleware.PersistentRemoteUserMiddleware), which will work when the authentication header is only present on the login page.

If you look at the [patch](https://github.com/django/django/commit/a570701e02e0bc09d977c8ae0b6ee987a1190039), it shouldn't be too hard to do something similar in Django 1.8. I would try overriding `process_request` so that it doesn't call `self._remove_invalid_user(request)` to log out your user (that might end up duplicating a lot of code), or overriding `_remove_invalid_user` itself.

Comment: This is good news, I added this as a TODO item for the time of our Django 1.9 transition. Thanks for pointing it out, I will just do that!