# Session Variable Prefixes in Django Memcached Session Store

Tags: python, django, session

We have several services that will be sharing a session stored in memcached. Each service will have a prefix for its session variables. In implementing this for a Django app I created a custom session store that inherits the Cache backend session store. In an effort to prepend all of the variables that both django and developers will set, I overwrote the magic methods for get, set, del, and contains.

```
from django.contrib.sessions.backends.cache import SessionStore as CacheSessionStore
from django.conf import settings    

class SessionStore(CacheSessionStore):

    key_prefix = settings.SESSION_PREFIX

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        new_key = self.key_prefix + key
        return super(SessionStore, self).__setitem__(new_key, value)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        new_key = self.key_prefix + key
        return super(SessionStore, self).__getitem__(new_key)

    def __contains__(self, key):
        new_key = self.key_prefix + key
        return super(SessionStore, self).__contains__(new_key)

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        new_key = self.key_prefix + key
        return super(SessionStore, self).__delitem__(new_key)
```

The result is that no login happens, I just keep getting returned to the login page. In stepping through debug, I see that it is creating the session keys with my prefix and creating the session within memcachced. The initial login varibles get saved to the session in memcached successfully after it authenticates my user.  Somewhere along the line it decides that I'm an AnonomousUser and returns me to the login page. The session that it creates during the process exists within memcached. After I am returned to the login screen, I don't see my sessionid within my cookies.

The RemoteUser middleware is flushing the session. I'm at a loss here.

Comment: I think your problem is the RemoteUser middleware, not your custom session store. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32397610/113962).

Comment: It doesn't give me any trouble though when I pass key straight to the super method. It is only when using this new_key. It is this try that fails: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/middleware.py#L68

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I needed to overwrite the get and pop methods as well.

```
def get(self, key, default=None):
    new_key = self.key_prefix + key
    return super(SessionStore, self).get(new_key, default)

def pop(self, key, *args):
    new_key = self.key_prefix + key
    return super(SessionStore, self).pop(new_key, *args)
```